# QML WebView Blank on Android

Tags: android, qt, webview, qml

I am showing a Qt QML WebView for a working link. It works as expected on Windows and iOS, but on Android the view is black or blank. The loadRequest completes successfully and the visible property is true. All other QML screens in the app display correctly.

If I switch to another app, like Settings, and then return, the WebView then works as expected from there on out.

Any ideas on what might be going on? QtWebView::initialize() is called on app start.

Comment: How you load the page on application start?

Comment: The WebViews are loaded from a menu. They provide supplemental information to the user. So they are loaded when the user presses their menu item. The url property is set and the view is displayed. I monitor the visibleChanged and loadingChanged signals and both loading and visibility complete as expected.